# Video live streaming directly from browser

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

**I currently triying to use Azure Media Services, but if there is any other solution, i would aprreciate it!**

Is there any way to use Azure Media Services Live Video directly from browser?

I mean, i want to capture user Webcam on the browser, then send the stream directly to the Azure Media Services ingest endpoint, without any server in the middle (maybe a server to authentication only to generate the ingest URL).

All i want is to use javascript and HTML 5 to send stream to Azure Media Services Live video, then i distribute it on a client application, based on C# web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would require support for WebRTC on ingest. We do not support WebRTC broadcasting from the browser at this time. No roadmap currently.

Comment: You could also look at services like Restream.io - not sure if they take WebRTC as input and relay...